# Python & JSON Parsing. TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json

I'm a complete amateur at python and programming.  I'm trying to read a list of data from a JSON datafile on a server.  It generates the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I believe it goes back to this statement which needs some sort of change, but I don't know what it should be.

```
def grabDeviceIDs():
    devices=[];
    ## parse the list
    for deviceListJSON in (getDeviceListFromserver()['mobile_device_group']['mobile_devices']['mobile_device']):
        d = Device()
        d.id = deviceListJSON.get('id')
        devices.append(d)  
    print "Found " + str(len(devices)) + " devices."
    return devices
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post an example of the json returned ?

Comment: You have a list in your structure where you think there is a dictionary. We'll need to see the structure.

Comment: Specifically, the `mobile_devices` key sounds as if it'll reference a list.

Comment: Sure here's a sample output…  {'mobile_device_group': {'name': 'Bla'}, 'mobile_devices': [{'name': 'deviceA', 'udid': 'xxx8f9c0ac13df3113c998763d2246b8a392aca8', 'id': 50}, {'name': 'deviceB', 'udid': 'xxxf4e984ec848608650e1a039a80ed069d37a3b', 'id': 72}],'id': 555}}

Comment: `mobile_devices` is a list there; none of the contained dictionaries have a `mobile_device` key.

Comment: As MartijnPieters mentioned, mobile_devices is a list and not a dictionary so you must use intergers.

Comment: I found the error.  ['mobile_device'] was unnecessary

Comment: Your JSON looks invalid, BTW. In JSON, strings are enclosed in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: @Barmar: this is the Python structure after decoding.

Answer (score 1):

You have one key too many; this should suffice:

```
for deviceListJSON in getDeviceListFromserver()['mobile_device_group']['mobile_devices']:
```